# If A is nilpotent, and B is an invertible matrix of the same order as A and AB =BA, then B- A is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, nilpotence

[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikTw6.png)

I am quite sure that my proof is wrong, because I did not use the fact that AB= BA in the proof, is there a way to prove that B-A is singular without using determinant?

Comment: You did use $AB=BA$ in the proof. The formula $B^m-A^m = (B-A)(\ldots)$ would not work if $AB \neq BA$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Right, I noticed that after expanding, so is my proof complete/correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me! But you don't need the determinant : if $B^m = (B-A)(...) = (...)(B-A)$, then $B$ is invertible, so $B^m$ is invertible hence there exists $C$ such that $CB^m = I = B^mC$, you can now find an explicit inverse for $B-A$ using $C$ and $(...)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that $C=AB^{-1}$ is nilpotent (here you use the fact that matrices commute). Then $(I-C)(1+C+C^2+...)=I$. So $(I -AB^{-1}) $ is invertible. Multiply it by invertible $B$ and get that $B-A$ is invertible.

Comment: Is this using the fact that the product of 2 invertible matrices is invertible? (I- AB^-1)(B) = B- A. If I multiply by B on LHS, then the RHS would be I(B) = B ? I wouldn't be able to show that (B-A) (....) = I

Comment: If you multiply $I-AB^{-1}$ by $B$, you are multiplying two invertible matrices. So the product is invertible too.